# phpstorm search selection jumps to next occurrence

Tags: ide, phpstorm, usability

I use PhpStorm for years and have a habbit to select some word to find all its occurences in file.

Before phpstorm 10 when I select some word and press Ctrl+F, it just highlighted the word, cursor **stayed on the word** (and its occurences) and it showed search panel at the top of editor with matches count.

After upgrade to phpstorm 10 it became work in other way. Now when I select some word and press Ctrl+F it immediately jumps to next occerence of the selected word (it may be e.g. on the other end of the file).

That's very annoying - have to hit Back to move to the place where I started searching.

Does anybody know the reason of it? Maybe there is a way to disable such new behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like a bug or a new setting I'm not aware of. I'm not having this issue on my Phpstorm 10 installation (OS X version, maybe that makes a difference). Try creating an issue on the [JetBrains bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI).

Comment: @Oldskool I installed ohostorm10 to os x and I see there is the same issue (and on Linux Mint too).
Actually I submitted this to Jetbrain's bugtraker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29792